# How to make POS n-grams more effective?

Tags: python, nlp, svm

I am doing text classification with SVM, using POS n-grams as features. But it take me 2 hours to complete only POS unigram. I have 5000 texts, in each text there are 300 words. Here is my code:

```
def posNgrams(s,n):
    '''Calculate POS n-grams and return a dictionary'''
    text = nltk.word_tokenize(s)
    text_tags = nltk.pos_tag(text)
    taglist = []
    output = {}
    for item in text_tags: 
        taglist.append(item[1])
    for i in xrange(len(taglist)-n+1):
        g = ' '.join(taglist[i:i+n])
        output.setdefault(g,0)
        output[g] += 1
    return output
```

I tried the same method to do character n-grams and it only took me several minutes. Could you give me some idea about how to make my POS n-grams faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a server with these specs from `inxi -C`:

```
CPU(s): 2 Hexa core Intel Xeon CPU E5-2430 v2s (-HT-MCP-SMP-) cache: 30720 KB flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) 
Clock Speeds: 1: 2500.036 MHz
```

Normally, the canonical answer is to use batch tagging with `pos_tag_sents` but it doesn't seem that it's faster.

Let's try to profile some of the steps before you get the POS tags (using just 1 core):

```
import time

from nltk.corpus import brown
from nltk import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize, pos_tag
from nltk import pos_tag_sents

# Load brown corpus
start = time.time()
brown_corpus = brown.raw()
loading_time = time.time() - start
print "Loading brown corpus took",  loading_time

# Sentence tokenizing corpus
start = time.time()
brown_sents = sent_tokenize(brown_corpus)
sent_time = time.time() - start
print "Sentence tokenizing corpus took", sent_time


# Word tokenizing corpus
start = time.time()
brown_words = [word_tokenize(i) for i in brown_sents]
word_time = time.time() - start
print "Word tokenizing corpus took", word_time

# Loading, sent_tokenize, word_tokenize all together.
start = time.time()
brown_words = [word_tokenize(s) for s in sent_tokenize(brown.raw())]
tokenize_time = time.time() - start
print "Loading and tokenizing corpus took", tokenize_time

# POS tagging one sentence at a time took.
start = time.time()
brown_tagged = [pos_tag(word_tokenize(s)) for s in sent_tokenize(brown.raw())]
tagging_time = time.time() - start
print "Tagging sentence by sentence took", tagging_time


# Using batch_pos_tag.
start = time.time()
brown_tagged = pos_tag_sents([word_tokenize(s) for s in sent_tokenize(brown.raw())])
tagging_time = time.time() - start
print "Tagging sentences by batch took", tagging_time
```

[out]:

```
Loading brown corpus took 0.154870033264
Sentence tokenizing corpus took 3.77206301689
Word tokenizing corpus took 13.982845068
Loading and tokenizing corpus took 17.8847839832
Tagging sentence by sentence took 1114.65085101
Tagging sentences by batch took 1104.63432097
```

Note: that the `pos_tag_sents` was previously called `batch_pos_tag` in version before NLTK3.0

In conclusion, i think you would need to consider other POS tagger to preprocess your data or you have to use `threading` to handle the POS tags.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please give me some suggestion of other POS tagger that can be used to do the text classification task? Or could you tell me what problems my code has?

Comment: Can you give some some suggestion of how to improve the efficiency of my code?

Comment: the bottleneck is the POS tagger, there's nothing much you can do. Use a faster/better POS tagger.

Comment: Besides the NLTK POS tagger, I also tried Stanford Parser and used it to get POS tagger, but it seems even slower than NLTK. Could you please recommend me some faster/better POS tagger?

Comment: Shameless plug for my own implementation: The BUBS parser includes a POS tagger that usually runs at 150-250k words/second (accuracy on WSJ text is around 96.5%; lower on other genres of course). See the wiki page on POS tagging at https://code.google.com/p/bubs-parser/wiki/POSTagging, and feel free to contact me if you want a pre-trained POS tagging model.